# Databricks catalog schemas not showing in Qlik data loading

Tags: azure, databricks, database-connection, qliksense

I am working in a project where we have a BI development consuming data from a Databricks Catalog.
We had it working fine until we updated our Qlik on premise version to 14.129.12.

That's when the connection started showing errors: the connection is successfull, but the schemas from the catalog are not present for connsultation.

[Here is the print that shows the data loading with no schema present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RwHC.png) Only the default schemas are present.

[Here is the print that shows the schemas in the catalog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QORTK.png)

The Databricks service used is hosted on Microsoft Azure.

I'm lost and don't know how to fix this. I've heard that maybe trying a different type of connection to the Databricks, such as JBDC, might work, but I found on material online and have no idea how to do it.

Would very much appreciate help.

Edit: found some material online:

[A response in Qlik community that states that there is no way to make JBDC connections on the on premise version.](https://community.qlik.com/t5/App-Development/JDBC-Connection-Qlik-Sense-On-Premise/td-p/2011198)

[Qlik documentation that states that Qlik Cloud only connects via JBDC to Dynamo, Cassandra, CouchDB, Marketo and SAP.](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/JDBC_connector_help/Content/Connectors_JDBC/Introduction/JDBC-connector.htm)

[Qlik documentation that indicates databricks connection only through ODBC.](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/ODBC_connector_help/Content/Connectors_ODBC/Databricks/Load-Databricks-data.htm)

[Qlik documentation on Data Gateways.](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Gateways/setting-up-gateways.htm) I had not understood this functionality, but from what I gathered, it's not in the direction I want. The data I want to connect to is on the cloud, not in a on-premise machine/data base. My Qlik Sense is the one running on a on premise enviroment.

From the On Premise, there were not options for JBDC or Direct Access when searching for possible connections. [You can see the print here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUDlq.png). So I suspect there is no other way to connect the Qlik with Databricks other than the usual way, via the setup new connection.

Comment: Please, share the online material that you found so others can look at it.

Comment: @PéterSzilvási I have updated the post with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out there is a problem in the version 14.129.12, which we were using, that messes up the driver to connect with Databricks. To solve this I advise trying to update to newer versions.

If updating is out of the question, you can bypass the problem installing directly the [Databricks ODBC connector](https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download). Here is the [Databricks documentation on how to set it up](https://docs.databricks.com/en/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html).

I'd also advise watching [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt8Rt-pYQOk&ab_channel=ShareCloudTech).

That way, you have to create a ODBC connection from Qlik and use this driver.
Note that the username = 'token' and password = configured databricks-token.